Match punctuation sign or end of a line
I want to improve the NLTK sentence tokenizer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work too well when the text doesn't leave any whitespace between the period and the next sentence.
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

text = "I love you.i hate you.I understand. i comprehend. i have 3.5 lines.I am bored"

sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
sentences

Output:
['I love you.i hate you.I understand.',
 'i comprehend.',
 'i have 3.5 lines.I am bored']

So with regex I can split the first line into 3 separate sentences. However, I don't know how can I get the last sentence too, which doesn't end in a punctuation sign.
import re

new_sentences = []
for i in sentences:
    sents = re.findall(r'\w+.*?[.?!$](?!\d)', i, flags=re.S)
    new_sentences.extend(sents)
new_sentences

Output:
['I love you.',
 'i hate you.',
 'I understand.',
 'i comprehend.',
 'i have 3.5 lines.']

I put the $ there indicating end of line, but it doesn't seem to care.

You may use this regex for your matches to allow last match to match till end position:
\b\w+.*?(?:[.?!$](?!\d)|$)

RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

\b: Match word boundary
\w+: Match 1+ word characters
.*?: Match 0 or more of any characters (lazy)
(?:: Start non-capture group

[.?!$]: Match terminators . or ? or ! or $
(?!\d): Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have digit at immediate next position
|: OR
$: Match end position


): End non-capture group

Code:
>>> import re
>>> text = "I love you.i hate you.I understand. i comprehend. i have 3.5 lines.I am bored"
>>> print (re.findall(r'\b\w+.*?(?:[.?!$](?!\d)|$)', text, flags=re.S))
['I love you.', 'i hate you.', 'I understand.', 'i comprehend.', 'i have 3.5 lines.', 'I am bored']


@zest16 - Consider marking it as an answer if it works for you. This way, it will help future visitors to this page. You can check this for more information.

Try text.split('.'). It gives you ['I love you', 'i hate you', 'I understand', ' i comprehend', ' i have 3', '5 lines', 'I am bored']
Is it just the last item that is missing the full stop?  Not sure how to fix the decimal point though/

What about sentences ending with ? or ! (which the OP's regex currently covers)?
